# How to pass variables from azure pipeline to bash script in my local machine

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to take the variables from the azure pipeline and set it into my bash script but i need to bring those variables values from the pipeline and then set into my local config file suggest me how to do it

Comment: Can you provide the YAML you are using? This will help others see what activities you are doing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.